# Call routing from symfony command

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use call an API in my symfony command.
To possibilities
- I hard code URL of API
- I declare this URL in routing.yml

I prefere declare it in routing.yml

```
iot:
path: XX.XX.XX.XX/{id}
schemes: ['http']
```

Next, I want to call my path of iot in a command, or anywhere in php code.
In javascript i'm using {{url()}}
But in PHP I don't know how it works...

Someone can help me and have a solution ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Symfony you should declare this URL in your .env file.
Then you can use [The Dotenv Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html) to retrieve it.

Comment: This assumes you are wanting to access a 3rd-party / external API resource.